# Why are " preferred over ' in R

Tags: string, r

From `help("'")`:

> Single and double quotes delimit character constants. They can be used
>   interchangeably but double quotes are preferred (and character
>   constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are
>   normally only used to delimit character constants containing double
>   quotes.

If they are interchangeable, why are double quotes preferred?  I've yet to find a difference between them in my own usage.  Particularly surprising is that mixed character vectors are allowable:

```
> c("a",'b',"c")
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

**Edit**

I'm really asking two questions here, I guess:

1. Are there any situations in which `'` and `"` behave differently?
2. If not, why was `"` chosen as the preferred version by convention?

Answers so far have been related to (2), but (1) is at least as much of-interest.

Comment: one possibility: less chance of confusion with commonly used characters like backquotes and accents, and with single quotes used within text data (such as in names, like "O'Reilly").

Comment: As far as I can tell this documentation was added on 14 June 2005 by Brian Ripley: https://github.com/wch/r-source/commit/d5871a12861d420cc7821e7523dfcd57e1316fcf#src/library/base/man/Quotes.Rd

Answer (score 12):

I do not know of any cases where single-quotes are different than doubles. I think the preference is due to readability and to avoid potential confusion of single quotes with back-ticks which *are* handled differently. It's probably very hard for the eye-brain system in the wetware to pick up a mismatched back-tick paired with a single quote.

```
> `newfn` <- function() {}
> newfn
function() {}
> "newfn" <- function() {}
> newfn
function() {}
> 'newfn' <- function() {}
> newfn
function() {}
> var <- c(`a`, "b", 'c')
Error: object 'a' not found
> var <- c( "b", 'c')
> var
[1] "b" "c"
> a <- 1
> identical(`a`, a)
[1] TRUE
```

So for assignment to names, they (s-quotes, d-quotes, and back-ticks)  are all handled the same on the LHS of assignment from `function`, but the unquoted `a` and the back-ticked `a` are the same on the command line and are different than either of the quoted "a" or 'a'.

The other situation where there may be a difference is in data input. Persons' names may have single quotes and it not case you may want to review the handling of the two different kinds of quotes by the `read.table` function. By default it uses both types of quotes, but it may be necessary to "turn off" the quoting action of single quotes by setting `quote="\""` so that you don't get big blobs of data turned into a single text field by mistake. The `count.fields` function has the same defaults as read.table, so it makes sense to do a preliminary run with this to check for shortened lines cause by mismatched single quotes:

```
 table( count.fields('filnam.ext') )
```

Answer (score 7):

My guess is that "single quotes" occur much more often as apostrophes, so preferring double-quotes will reduce the chance of messing things up with an apostrophe.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the first question, *Are there any situations in which ' and " behave differently?*, I think it is important to note that since

```
identical("a", 'a')
TRUE
```

R users (including package developers) have no way of telling the difference, hence no way of creating different behaviors for one or the other.

Comment: That's true, but there could still be a parser difference.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid confusion for those who are accustomed to programming in the 
C family of languages (C, C++, Java), where there is a difference in 
the meaning of single quotes and double quotes. 
A C programmer reads 'a' as a single character and "a" as a character 
string consisting of the letter 'a' followed by a null character to 
terminate the string.  In R there is no character data type, there are 
only character strings.  For consistency with other languages it helps 
if character strings are delimited by double quotes.  The single quote 
version in R is for convenience.  On most keyboards you don't need to 
use the shift key to type a single quote but you do need the shift for 
a double quote.

Comment: *For consistency with other languages it helps if character strings are delimited by double quotes*. Well, that depends what other language you are talking about. Perl programmers will find it more consistent to use single quotes since R strings are never interpreted. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/contrasting-single-and-double-quotes-in-perl.html